# App freezes when scrolling in tableview

Tags: iphone

My app freezes when scrolling in tableview. It loads the data, but when I try to scroll, the app freezes immediately. What is the problem? My cellforrowatindexpath method is:

```
if (cell == nil) { 

    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCellView" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
}

getDats *gDatas=[[[getDats alloc]init]autorelease];

gDatas=[self.bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

const char *prior = "High"; 

const char *prior1 =[gDatas.Priority UTF8String]; 

if (strcmp(prior1 , prior) == 0)
 {
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"highPriority" ofType:@"png"]; 

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];   
}

[cell.MOwner setText:gDatas.WhatId];

[cell.DueDate setText:gDatas.EndDateTime];

[cell.theTextLabel setText:gDatas.Subject];

[cell.Descri setText:gDatas.Desc];

[cell.TaskId setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d" , gDatas.rowId]];  

cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

return cell;
```

and the debugger shows:

> -[__NSCFString Priority]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7341790
>   2012-07-09 10:23:46.761 MeetingMaker[716:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString Priority]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7341790'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1cbf052 0x2152d0a 0x1cc0ced 0x1c25f00 0x1c25ce2 0xf449 0x4e7e0f 0x4e8589 0x4d3dfd 0x4e2851 0x48d301 0x1cc0e72 0x29492d 0x29e827 0x224fa7 0x226ea6 0x2c037a 0x2c01af 0x1c93966 0x1c93407 0x1bf67c0 0x1bf5db4 0x1bf5ccb 0x2656879 0x265693e 0x44ea9b 0xe0c2 0x1e15)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(gdb) .

The app shows an error on line:

```
const char *prior1 =[gDatas.Priority UTF8String];
```

and shows

> Thread:Program received signal SIGABRT .

Answer (score 1):

You need to reuse your cells, when you scroll down a UITableView, cells that are no longer in view get reused, for that you need to set a resuseIdentifier to the cell.

From the [UITableViewCell docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
reuseIdentifier
A string used to identify a cell that is reusable. (read-only)

@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *reuseIdentifier
Discussion
The reuse identifier is associated with a UITableViewCell object that the table-view’s delegate creates with the intent to reuse it as the basis (for performance reasons) for multiple rows of a table view. It is assigned to the cell object in initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier: and cannot be changed thereafter. A UITableView object maintains a queue (or list) of the currently reusable cells, each with its own reuse identifier, and makes them available to the delegate in the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method.
```

Therefore you should be starting your method with something like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {      
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

}

Comment: thanks fr ur reply. i missed to paste that piece of code when asking the question. i still face the same pblm. i now get an error that says Thread1:program received signal:"EXC BAD ACCESS" in main.m file.

Comment: i fixed this issue.removed autorelease property and it worked out.